# Do I still need to remove extensions in every href for htaccess to work?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

Hello I am currently using wampserver and this code to remove file extensions.

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Yes, it is working but, I have lots of php files. Is there a way that it can automatically remove file extensions without me removing it from hrefs like `<a href="index.php"> to <a href="index">` ? And also I have links like `http://www.whatever.ph/index.php?pid=51` and I want it to be like `http://www.whatever.ph/index/51` or what is a better link for that

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need help writing URL Rewrite rule Regular Expression for PHP and htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10507754/need-help-writing-url-rewrite-rule-regular-expression-for-php-and-htaccess)

Answer (score 0):

You can do some global search/replace to get rid of all the .php extensions. You really want to change the links in your html otherwise you'll need to create mod_rewrite rules to redirect the browser for every request that has an extension or the ugly looking links.

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+([^\?]+)\.php\?pid=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [L,R]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+([^\?]+)\.php(\ |$)
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/([0-9]+)$ /$1.php?pid=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Hello, I've used your htaccess and tested it on 2 php files.
First one is test.php and then output.php
In test.php the code is only <a href="output.php?pid=5"> TEST LINK</a> and in output.php the code is only <?= $GET['pid']; ?>. The url becomes http://localhost/test/output/5 but it gives an error 404
The requested URL /tests/output/5.php was not found on this server.

Comment: @FewFlyBy Because you've got more slashes in the URL now, you need to use absolute URLs: `<a href="/output.php?pid=5">`, because the slashes change the relative URL base.

Comment: It is working but my problem now is, I have too many php pages. I'll manually add / to every php file then?

Comment: @FewFlyBy either that or add `<base href="/" />` to the header of all your pages